# MySQL Error 10048 on nested Delphi Queries

Tags: mysql-5

I'm having a problem with MySQL (Server 5.1.11) interfacing with a Delphi application

The problem occurs when trying to use the application to do a bulk export to Excel.  During the application queries for a list matching projects (Query A), then for each matching project the details of the Project are requested from the database (Query B)

The error that occurs is

```
Can't Connect to MySQL Server on 'stkitts' (10048)
```

It generally occurs when trying to reach larger batches.  For example I am able to query the past 3 years (771 projects, 1150 records including details), but expanding to 4 years I error at only 443 records returned.

I've checked that my data is OK, and the error is not associated with specific records.  Repeating a search will break at a different point - although you are unlikely to get results for 4 years back...

The error can occur when reading a field or a new record.  So the returned Excel sheet may or may not have a complete line at the point the error occurred.

My gut feeling is that I am sending too much traffic to the DB server, but I am only using two connections to the database for the above queries (MySQL Administrator confirms that there are only 2 active connections during the export)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tracked it down, and once again it's Delphi's hidden "Autoclone" option that is the culprit.

Set Autoclone to False and the number of queries gets limited and the error is skipped.